# gomobile does not support c-archive for android

Tags: go, gomobile, gomobile-android

When i tried to build a static library with 'gomobile bind' tools, i got this error:
invalid value "c-archive" for flag -buildmode: buildmode c-archive not supported on android/arm

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's falling back [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/work/init.go#L218), hence atm android is not supported for `c-archive` flag. I am not sure why though, since [this condition](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/770f1de8c54256d5b17447028e47b201ba8e62c8/src/cmd/internal/sys/supported.go#L69) should return true.